# Excel VBA IE automation - paste link to spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have VBA code that connects to IE, bbc.co.uk and searches for whatever text is in cell A1.

I want the first result for the search to be pasted into cell A2 on the spreadsheet.

The emelement I want to copy/paste is 'summary short'.

My code is below - it all works apart from the very end:

```
Sub FillInBBCSearchForm()

Dim ieApp As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim words As Range

Set words = Range("A1")

ieApp.Visible = True

'go to the website of interest
ieApp.Navigate "http://www.bbc.co.uk/"

Do While ieApp.Busy
DoEvents
Loop

'wait for page to finish loading
Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

'****fill in the search form
ieApp.Document.getElementById("orb-search-q").Value = words
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'wait for page to finish loading
Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop

'****click the search button
ieApp.Document.all("orb-search-button").Click

'wait for page to finish loading
Do While ieApp.Busy And Not ieApp.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop


'Select the first article heading and paste it to cell A2
For Each elm In ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary short")
If InStr(elm.innerText, "@") Then
    Range("A2").Value = innerText
End If
Next elm

'Set out1 = ieApp.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary short")(0).innertext

End Sub
```

Comment: Right off the bat I notice that you have `ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary short")` but your declared variable name is not `ie` but rather `ieApp`.  This is why I always add `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module, as this code wouldn't even run because improper variable declarations would be found.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed a couple of things.

First, you have declared `ieApp` as your `InternetExplorer` object but you are trying to use `ie` instead.  Additionally, on the line `Range("A2").Value = innerText` you haven't said which object's `innetText` you actually want.  That line should be `Range("A2").Value = elm.innerText` instead.

So this:

```
For Each elm In ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary short")
If InStr(elm.innerText, "@") Then
    Range("A2").Value = innerText
End If
Next elm
```

Should be this:

```
For Each elm In ieApp.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary short")
If InStr(elm.innerText, "@") Then
    Range("A2").Value = elm.innerText
End If
Next elm
```

To avoid errors like this, I add `Option Explicit` to my modules outside of any subroutines.  This forces explicit variable declaration and, in addition to being good practice, will catch these errors before the code even executes and could save you a few hours of debugging just to find out that you mistyped a variable name.  This will also help you figure out what you were trying to do when you come back to old code that you haven't visited in some time.

If you do add `Option Explicit` it will force you to declare `elm` as something.  You can add `Dim elm As Object` at the beginning of your code to remedy this issue (as the `getElementsByClassName` method returns an object collection).

Comment: Thanks for your help - i am getting a Run-time error '438' Object doesnt support this property or method for the line       `code` For Each elm In ieApp.Document.getElementsByClassName("summary short") `code`

Comment: Did you declare `Dim elm as Object` with your other variable declarations?  The code executed alright when I tested it in Excel 2013 on my machine.

Comment: I did declare it, still getting runtime error 438. Im using Excel 2007 with IE 6 (dont ask why I have to use this version).

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is [not supported in IE6](http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/), I think we might have to try a workaround if you cannot upgrade your IE version.

Comment: thats ok, i will try and get an update! Thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: No problem, there are workarounds to using that.  For example, you could use `getElementsByTagName` and filter down.  It might be a hassle, but I am still thinking a bit about another way.